# C# targeting multiple frameworks

Tags: c#-7.3

I've tried doing some searching on this but as I am unsure of "what" this is I didn't get very far so it's most likely a duplicate of another question I couldn't find.

I'm looking at a piece of code for a little test application and noticed the "Target Framework" drop down in properties was disabled.  Editing the .csproj file shows me this:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net451;netcoreapp1.0;netcoreapp2.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

Looking a little lower down in the file, I see this:

```
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' != 'netstandard2.0'">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="1.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="1.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net451' ">
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Would someone please just point me in the right direction to understand what this is, how this works and what it's use case is?

Further to that then, looking at this directive for a Task

```
#if NET451
            return Task.FromResult(true);
#else
            return Task.CompletedTask;
#endif
```

I note that the NET451 is enabled and I'm trying to find out why this is the one it selected instead of netstandard2.0?  Normally I could just select the targeted framework but as I mentioned, the drop down is disabled, so I'm trying to understand how it's selecting the one it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at `TargetFramework` as the current target from `TargetFrameworks`. MSBuild will build each target at a time.

Sadly, there's still no UI for `TargetFrameworks`.

The way you choose which one is active in Visual Studio is in the top left combo box at the top of the editor window.

Comment: Ok, so finally I found the little bugger hiding in the drop down for the web server (I don't even know what that drop down is called).  It looks like VS creates a new entry there once you target multiple frameworks.  Interesting indeed!